# FCM Push notification not working on wearOS if the watch is configured using an iPhone

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging, wear-os

I am developing a realtime chatting application for android wear-OS. I am using Tic Watch Pro 4G for developmental testing. My app is already on Wear-OS play store by the name "IoSite"

For push notifications, I am using FCM. I have two watches

Case 1:If I configure the watches using Android phone and the download IoSite App from play store then FCM Push notification works in both the watches.

Case 2: If I configure the watches using iPhone. Then when I download the IoSite App into watch 1 and try to use it. Then FCM push notification works fine. Then I download the IoSite app in watch 2 and try to use it. FCM push notification works in watch two a well. But after the app is installed in watch 2, the FCM push notification stops working in watch 1. Below is the Android studio log when the app tries to get firebase instance-id:

> 2020-02-14 16:39:39.455 9476-9662/com.iosite.iositewatchapp
>   W/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed without exception
>   message. Will retry token retrieval 2020-02-14 16:39:39.459
>   9476-9476/com.iosite.iositewatchapp W/MyFirebaseMessagingService:
>   getInstanceId failed
>       java.io.IOException: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
>           at com.google.firebase.iid.zzl.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.0.2:71)
>           at com.google.firebase.iid.zzl.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.0.2:84)
>           at com.google.firebase.iid.zzp.then(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.0.2:4)
>           at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzd.run(Unknown Source:5)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

In this watch 1, if i try to deleteInstanceID (so that a new ID is generated by FCM SDK) then i get the following error:

> 2020-02-14 16:39:39.461 9476-9476/com.iosite.iositewatchapp
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.deleteInstanceId(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.0.2:57)
>   2020-02-14 16:39:39.462 9476-9476/com.iosite.iositewatchapp
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.iosite.iositewatchapp.Services.MyFirebaseMessagingService$2.onComplete(MyFirebaseMessagingService.java:407)

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Did you get an answer to this? Do you have any sample code for Wear OS listener for firebase messages?

Comment: any news? did you solve the problem somehow?

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
        private final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMessaging";
        private Context mContext;
        public static final String CHANNEL_ID = "NotifChannel";
        public static final String CHANNEL_ID_ANN = "AnnouncementChannel";
        public static final String CHANNEL_ID_MSG = "MsgChannel";
        private String fcm_token = "";
        public static List<MessageClass> messages = new ArrayList<>();
        Location location;
        private Vibrator audioVibe;
        private VibrationEffect audioVibeEffect;
    public MyFirebaseMessagingService() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }


    public MyFirebaseMessagingService(Context context) {
        Log.i(TAG, "MyFirebaseMessagingService started");
        mContext = context;

    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onMessageReceived called: " + remoteMessage.getData());

        Map<String, String> messageReceivedData = remoteMessage.getData();
        if (messageReceivedData.size() > 0) {
            //TODO: handle new group added notif and subscribe for the group. Also add group to group list
//            sendMessageNotification(messageReceivedData);
        }

        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String token) {
        Log.d(TAG, "New token generated: " + token);
        fcm_token = token;
//        sendRegistrationToServer(token, FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getId());
    }


    public boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Context context) {
        GoogleApiAvailability googleApiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        int resultCode = googleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context);
        return resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS;
    }
```

Also, add the following to your app-level build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.2'
```

Add the following to your manifest:

```
 <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:exported="false">
```

After the above code, you also need to add your project to your fcm account. You will get a google-services.json file after adding the project. Save that file at `C:\Users\{xyz}\AndroidStudioProjects\{your_app_name}\app\`

You should be able to receive all the notifications in the call back method `onMessageReceived`.